# How to disable "all" option from contextual filter?

Tags: 7, views

While debugging some slow running queries I came across a "hidden feature"?  in views. 
When I have a "uid" contextual filter and pass "all" as the value it will show all users.

Answer (score 6):

Ok, found it. In the contextual filter there is an "Exception" option that you can expand. "all" seems to be added by default for all contextual filters.